# For 4 balls having diameters $26,24,13$ and $9$ cm, find minimum length of a closed parallelepiped where the four balls can be placed.

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry, spheres, packing-problem

I have 4 balls which diameters are $26, 24, 13$ and $9$ cm. What is the minimum length $L$ of a closed parallelepiped in which I can put the 4 balls? In the final answer please call $L, l$ and $W$ the 3 sides of the parallelepiped, with $ L \geq l \geq W $

When looking for references please do not look at the following (1) publications that look for solutions providing maximum density (this is not the objective function here); (2) publications dealing with balls of equal sizes; (3) publications on "stacking" (packing ≠ stacking).

I have looked at the following references without being able to find either the solution, or at least a good local minimum.

Stoyan, Y.G., Scheithauer, G. & Yaskov, G.N. Packing Unequal Spheres into Various Containers. Cybern Syst Anal 52, 419–426 (2016). https://doi.org/10.1007/s10559-016-9842-1

Labib Yousef, Contribution à la résolution des problèmes de placement en trois dimensions, Doctorate University de Picardie Jules Verne (France), 2017, 172 pages. Downloadable from: https://www.theses.fr/2017AMIE0020.pdf

On Google Scholar, the request < Packing "unequal spheres"  pdf > gives other references, almost all from 2016-2023 when you add to the request several names of researchers who made important contributions to the field (Hifi Stoyan Sutou Yousef).

Comment: Are you talking about what I call a cuboid with right angles or something that can slope?

Comment: Why are these particular four sizes of balls of interest? Where does this problem come from, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson. I suppose that they are spheres. Funny problem !

Comment: *Welcome to the site !*. If I may ask, are you in France ?

Comment: The answer is `{99.9199, 62.7898, 52.}`. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291235/packing-unequal-spheres-into-minimal-cuboid) for it.

Comment: @user, that question concerns minimizing length plus width plus depth, but the question here is just about minimizing length.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is not responding.

Comment: My answer is $(56,26,24)$ but since you are not responding ....

Answer (score 0):

You can fit them in a cube with side length $L=39.434$ by placing the centers as follows:
\begin{matrix}
i & x_i & y_i & z_i \\
\hline
1 &26.4338 &26.4338 &13.0000 \\
2 &12.0000 &12.0000 &27.4338 \\
3 &6.5011 &32.9331 &6.5000 \\ 
4 &34.9337 &4.5007 &34.9337
\end{matrix}

Given the radii $r_i$, the problem is to minimize $L$ subject to
\begin{align}
r_i \le x_i &\le L - r_i &&\text{for all $i$} \\
r_i \le y_i &\le L - r_i &&\text{for all $i$} \\
r_i \le z_i &\le L - r_i &&\text{for all $i$} \\
(x_i - x_j)^2 + (y_i - y_j)^2 + (z_i - z_j)^2 &\ge (r_i + r_j)^2 &&\text{for $i < j$}
\end{align}